# How can I add a task after do_deploy()?

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I have written a recipe where I want to execute a task after `do_deploy()`:

```
[...]

inherit deploy

[...]

do_deploy () {
    echo "do_deploy() has been called."
}
addtask deploy after do_compile

do_after_deploy () {
    echo "do_after_deploy() has been called."
}
addtask after_deploy after do_deploy
```

When I build the recipe the `do_deploy()` task is executed. However, the `after_deploy()` task is not.

When I manually execute the task with `bitbake my_recipe -c after_deploy` the instructions in the task are executed.

What is the reason for this? Is `do_deploy()` the very last task and BitBake doesn't let me add tasks after it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`do_deploy()` gets executed by default because base.bbclass happens to make `do_build` (the default task) depend on `do_deploy`.

You should be able to make your new task run by default with

```
addtask after_deploy after do_deploy before do_build
```

Comment: +1 the answer because it worked for me after a frustrating dependency chase.  But for the life of me, I can't imagine why you're forced to explicitly add **before do_build** in order for it to work as expected.  Is the default behavior **before do_infinity** or something similarly unhelpful?

Comment: addtask defines the order the tasks should be executed, it does not decide whether it should be executed. The actual tasks to run are decided in a backwards fashion: `build` is the final task, but before build all tasks that build needs will have to be executed (and so on). So `before do_build` make sure that the example task does get executed.